# Trying to find a correct implementation of EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Enclosed below is an example of one of the methods that I created.
Am I correctly implementing EF6? As you can see in my commented code I first tried to create a repository class.  I instead scrapped the repository class for this implementation.  
 However I am now getting errors because I am returning an IQueryable object and then closing the dbcontext.

So this led me to the question: Am I implementing EF6 correctly?

I could change the IQueryable to return a `List<obj>` or I could remove the `using (_myContext)` statement. 
I'm just trying to understand the correct way to implement my methods.

```
public IQueryable<MY_USERS> GetAllUsers()
{
    using (_myContext)
    {
        return _myContext.MY_USERS;
    }
    //MyRepository<MY_USERS> users = new MyRepository<MY_USERS>(_myContext);
    //return users.GetAll();
}
```

Updated example:

```
public void DeleteUser(string userName)
{   
    using (var context = new MyEFConn())
    {
        using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                context.MY_USER_GROUPS.RemoveRange(GetUserGroups(userName));
                context.MY_USERS.Remove(new MY_USERS { USER_NAME = userName });
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are big risks returning an `IQueryable` since the return type is lazy-loaded, and the client could easily add a `Where` clause or something that is not supported by the SQL.  Returning lists from public methods is the general best practice.

Comment: Is the using statement even necessary for the context?  It appears to be causing me more headaches because I'm trying to leverage existing methods and I have all of the methods wrapped with that using(_myContext) statement.

Comment: Yes you should dispose of it (which is what `using` does).  If disposing of the context is causing problems that means that you're still tied back to the context.  The answer is to detach from the context, not to keep the context hanging around indefinitely.

Comment: So in the case of a method that may call 2 existing methods in that class how would I get around that? (Each class is wrapped with the using statement)

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you add an example to your question?

Comment: I added an updated example. Now I changed things around some.  In this method I create a new instance of the context in the using statement.  It should then be disposed of when I'm all done.  However I now get a different error when I try to delete a user stating that it can't find the user in the context. (It exists in the database)

Comment: FYI - It would have been so much easier in this scenario if the tables were correctly linked but they aren't and that is out of my control.

Comment: You're asking two different questions here, the question about returning an `IQuerable<T>` is quite a different issue than the question of deleting a row with a `DBContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no no wrong or right, it just depends.

When you use IQueriable this mean that you can have common queries in your repository class and outside of it you can append additional filter.

```
GetAllUsers().Where(u=>u.UserType== 'Test').ToList()
```

You can also use include depends on your needs let say in MVC controller

```
GetAllUsers().Include(u=>u.Roles).Take(10).ToList();
```

Important thing to note, EF dont connect to db until you do ToList() or iterate throw query.

Lastly as you mentioned in comment always need to remember when you use IQuerieable that context could be disposed so this should be taken to consideration too.

On the other side could be good option return IEnumerable from repositories, so lets say if you want to load users you should have method which will require input parameters for paging, filtering or other stuff. This is useful for testing because you will be able to mock data.

About Delete it always depends on your requirements and if you need to remove all together or nothing than you need to use transactions IN addition it could be same about all CRUD.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions.  It appears that one should be disposing of the context object. (In my case I was not creating a new instance of it in each method).  As for the return types it could be returned as a list or IEnumerable or even IQuerable depending on the situation.

Comment: Yes i forget to metioned about disposing.